# iOS GameCenter leaderboard shows only my score in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard, appstore-sandbox

I've created a leaderboard in the sandbox mode for my game. Then I tried to play the game using different gamecenter accounts. But I can see only the score for currently logged-in account. Is it correct? Or I have missed something? How can I fill up a sandbox leaderboard with a bunch of records to test my game?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal. In sandbox mode you can only see your own scores.

After you submit your app to the appstore and it doesn't use sandbox mode, you can see everyone's scores. (Gamecenter doesn't update instantly though, so you might have to wait a little while)

Comment: But you should see more than just one of your own scores, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106898/only-one-result-showing-in-game-center-leaderboard-sandbox-normal

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect, since I'm seeing a friend's score now.

Comment: In sandbox mode? not sure then... apple may have changed it since I posted this

Comment: Yes, Sandbox mode, but not the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm writing my response as an answer. The same thing happened to me. I had made a bunch of sandbox test accounts and found that I could only see the score of the currently logged in player.

However, after a period of time (I wasn't sure exactly how long), the scores for other players showed up on the leaderboard. So maybe just give it a few hours or so for the scores to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see that scores. It takes time , for the real accounts it's same too . But there is a trick to see more quickly that just log out and log in (switch) between that accounts , this forces the apple servers to display new scores for you more quickly.